# Google PlayStore - "QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I´m trying to upload an app to the Google-Playstore. It has been rejected for production use by google, because the package "QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" is used.

Even though I removed the package from my App it´s still rejected for the same reason.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked your merged manifest? maybe one of the libraries is using this permission.

Comment: Thans for the reply. The merged Manifest doesnt contain QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES. I used Search_Everywhere to find the usage. If I include non-project Files, it is found in the Manifest class specified by Android_API_33. Could this be the reason for the reject? How would i get rid of it?

Comment: If it's defined in one of included files, it should be present in the merged manifest with the corresponding package. If it's not there, you should check all dependencies to find the one adding this permission.